# PyQt not working on some Mac OS X (El Capitan)

Tags: python, macos, pyqt

I have a network of 4 computers that run Mac OS X El Capitan. I programmed something using PyQt and when i launch the `.py` file from 2 computers i get the full GUI i designed, but the at the other 2 i get that Python "rocket" icon but nothing shows. (no output in the terminal either)

What could be the problem?
Like i said, they all run the same OS X version and python version as well.

Thanks!

Here's the code i have for launching it:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
my_widget = myWidget()
my_widget.show()
my_widget.setFixedSize(my_widget.size())  
my_widget.raise_()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What's the command you are running? and, What's the output in the terminal when you run this code?

Comment: the command is `python myscript.py` and there's no output in the terminal, it shows that "rocket" icon at the bottom as if the program was launched but nothing shows

Comment: (i edited my original post - now i only get that "rocket" icon but i can't see the GUI itself)

Comment: Well, can you post the content inside myWidget.py and myWidget.ui ? Have you tried re-run pyuic?